# Function to be used for keeping the last column

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr

When I use;
data = Filter(function(x) sd(x) > 0.1, df)
I lost the categorical variables (last column), thus I have to cbind.data.frame() to get the categorical variables back after filtered data. Is there any way to write up the function to just filter in those numerical variables with SD>0.1 and still keep categorical variables?

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlQpC.png)

The original data contain categorical variables (above picture). After, I remove the column which SD = 0 by using -- data = Filter(function(x) sd(x) > 0.1, df) --the categorical variable column is removed (below picture). I just want the column with SD=0 to be removed but I don't know how to properly wrap up in the function ().

[categorical variable column is removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLVkF.png)

Comment: Could you please show what the expected output should look like?

Comment: the output should contain only the column contain SD>0.1 and the last column should contain categorical variables like in the first picture.

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thank you very much for informing me of the way to communicate better, I really appreciate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following work for you?

```
library(tidyverse)

select_if(df, function(col) is.character(col) | (is.numeric(col) && sd(col) > 1))
```

Comment: for the column name; there are 882 columns, how can I apply to all with more simpler code?

Comment: Feel free to upvote/mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of `dplyr`, we can use `select` with `where`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    select(where(~ is.character(.)| (is.numeric(.) && sd(.) > 1)))
```

Reproducible example with `iris` dataset

```
data(iris)
iris %>% 
   select(where(~ is.character(.)| (is.numeric(.) && sd(.) > 1))) %>% 
   head
#  Petal.Length
#1          1.4
#2          1.4
#3          1.3
#4          1.5
#5          1.4
#6          1.7
```